# Windows CE 5.0 Detect dock (connection to PC) with ActiveSync disabled

Tags: .net, .net-3.5, compact-framework, windows-ce

The application is developed in .Net CF 3.5 for Windows CE 5.0.

Due to security concerns ActiveSync has been disabled on the device.
The following registry values have been set to achieve this:

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\ControlPanel\Comm\AutoCnct : 0
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\ControlPanel\Comm\Cnct : ""

To add to this, Softtick CardExport is being used to expose the storage via USB Mass Storage.
CardExport is always running in this mode with it's own USB driver.

The intention was to use CeRunAppAtEvent in coredll and register for **NOTIFICATION_EVENT_RS232_DETECTED**

However this only seems to work when CardExport is not active and the device is in ActiveSync mode.
I believe this is due to the OS not receiving the RS232 event as it's own ActiveSync drivers are not in operation.

Currently AC Power is being used to detect that the device is docked in it's cradle using **RequestPowerNotifications** in coredll and **GetSystemPowerStatusEx**.

However this isn't a viable long term solution as not all cradles in the end system will have AC power which means we cannot detect dock.

Is there anything that may have been missed that can be accessed in Windows CE 5.0 to help solve this issue?

Comment: Are you mixing terms? ActiveSync is part of Windows Mobile x.y and not of Windows CE. Windows CE normally uses a RAS connection.... If this is a Windows Mobile device then simply replace replog.exe with something of your own and activate ActiveSync as usual. This replog.exe will then be called for the event NOTIFICATION_EVENT_RS232_DETECTED with the event name in the args. On the PC side you may use GuestOnly and let wmdcbase.exe start instead of wmdc to avoid WMDC being launched to the GUI.

Comment: @josef Although it triggers the "Windows Mobile Device Center" dialog, WindowsCE really does support ActiveSync, see for instance https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa513321.aspx

Comment: I did not write about RAPI support but about Windows CE does not come with an "ActiveSync" application as Windows Mobile does. So, I assume, there will be no replog.exe on Windows CE.

Comment: @josef perhaps this will convince you: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms879772.aspx "Microsoft ActiveSync provides support for synchronizing data between a Windows-based desktop computer and Microsoft Windows CE-based devices." All WindowsCE devices I've worked with came with ActiveSync installed and enabled. Or am I seeing this the wrong way?

Comment: Can you please add the exact Windows OS running on the device? Or, perhaps, the device's Model code?

Answer (score 0):

ActiveSync definitely works with any general Windows CE device (assuming it has ActiveSync in the OS image, of course).

Unfortunately, `CeRunAppAtEvent` is a non-starter for you, as you've found.  IIRC, none of the events will fire if you're in guest mode, though just for grins I'd try out NOTIFICATION_EVENT_SYNC_END as well.

Since this is the USB client connection, it's probably not likely you'll get a device notification from the device driver subsystem, but that's the direction I'd lean.  See if any notification (using [`RequestDeviceNotifications`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms919831.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)) show up.  Just pass in a `NULL` for the devclass to get all notifications, then if you find one, change to using that devclass in production.

Comment: "Unfortunately, CeRunAppAtEvent is a non-starter for you, as you've found. IIRC, none of the events will fire if you're in guest mode". The event is fired on the Device and GuestMode is a setting on PC. I am running my PC with GuestMode (more than 5 devices in change) and ActiveSync fires on all devices (WinCE5/6, WM6, WM65 or WEH65 and WEC7) and on my PC. You are right, my WEC7 device has an app called ActiveSync, but the WinCE 6 one does not have, it uses RAS.

Comment: Thanks for all the feedback which confirmed my findings. I had to eventually rely on the USB Driver in CardExport that provided feedback.